# Using python3 how can get the total usable addresses from the following format:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python3 how can get the total usable addresses from the following format which is the stdout from an os.system() call:

```
------------------------------------------------
           TCP/IP NETWORK INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------
IP Entered = ..................: 215.1.7.0
CIDR = ........................: /24
Netmask = .....................: 255.255.255.0
Netmask (hex) = ...............: 0xffffff00
Wildcard Bits = ...............: 0.0.0.255
------------------------------------------------
Network Address = .............: 215.1.7.0
Broadcast Address = ...........: 215.1.7.255
Usable IP Addresses = .........: 254
First Usable IP Address = .....: 215.1.7.1
Last Usable IP Address = ......: 215.1.7.254
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Do you need to extract the number 254 from the line "Usable IP Addresses = .........: 254" in your example?

Comment: Yes, to extract the total usable addresses (254, 65534, etc.) and if there is a comma to strip it out so math can be done on the numbers extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `output_lines` is a list of lines from the `os.system()` call:

```
def find_usable_addresses(output_lines):
  for line in output_lines:
    if line.startswith('Usable IP Addresses'):
      value = line.split(': ')[1] # split to ('Usable...', '254') 
      return int(value)
```

This function will return `None` if the value is not found.

Comment: The problem is that `os.system()` does not return you the output stream of the command it runs. Try using [`popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) instead: `output_lines = os.popen('that command').readlines()`

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty formatting my comment to you and including the code.  It all ends up on a single word-wrapped line.  I appreciate your assistance and I will give os.popen() a go.

Comment: OK, I made some progress but I get this error  __ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '65,534\n'__  Do I need to somehow lose the comma?

Comment: Use `value.strip()` to remove the trailing newline.